# How to rewrite the javascript template string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify code from https://github.com/airblade/chartjs-ror/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/Chart.js

I need to rewrite the original string template `tooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%> - <%= value %>"`, I want to add `if else condition` into it.

But the  `template string` is really complex

How could I rewrite it with the following logic ?

### My rough logic is

```
if ( %value > 0) {%datasetLabel - %value}
else {
    %datasetLabel - "Empty value"
}
```

> % means variable in the above logic

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do (untested code, but you get the idea):

```
yourTemplate: "<%if (value > 0){%>"    +
"<%= datasetLabel - value %>"          +
"<%}%>"                                +
"<%else {%>"                           +
"<%= datasetLabel - \"Empty Value\"%>" +
"<%}%>"
```